# Why do mountains disappear into the distance?

Tags: optics, atmospheric-science

Traveling south on CA 99 we noticed that atmospheric conditions were exceptionally clear and played a little game attempting to determine how far away we could identify Shasta. As we got further and further away it got smaller, greyer, and harder to locate. I took to using these closer (green) low hills that were nearly aligned with it to locate it. As expected, the low hills went down below the horizon.

Yet proceeding south I managed to reacquire it (partially using Lassen as a reference point), and manage to mostly hold it for quite some time. As we were coming up on Chico, it started to get close to disappearing below the horizon. But that never happened. Just north of Chico, Shasta disappeared into blue sky while I was looking right at it. It did not go below the horizon. It was not occluded by any cloud or smoke or smog, nor by trees for that matter. There was no indication of an atmospheric disturbance. I didn't lose its location and fail to require it.

So why might Shasta have disappeared? What limit did I exceed that I could no longer see it?

(safety note: I was not the one driving, so I could indeed turn and look straight backwards for minutes at a time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it disappeared is the same as [why the sky is blue](https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/blue-sky/en/): [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) of light from air and small particles in it. When you're close to the mountain its light only travels a short distance through air, so you see it sharply. The further you go away from it the more of its light is scattered. Additionally the light of the mountain is mixed up with light from the sun. If sunlight is scattered towards you at a location of the path between the mountain and your eye it looks like it comes from the mountain (see drawing). The reason why it looks like the mountain becomes mixed with blue is the $\propto \lambda^{-4}$ efficiency of Rayleigh scattering.

[image]

Comment: This disappearing-mountain effect is how lord Rayleigh was able to estimate Avogadro's number from the fact that he could only just see Mount Everest from Darjeeling, which was 100 km away.